# Prove that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the upper half plane

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

I want to prove $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the upper half plane $\mathbb{U}:=\{z\in \Bbb C\ |\ \mathrm{Im}(z)>0\}$ by 
$$z\longmapsto \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
 Is it enough to say that since $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\c & d \end{pmatrix}\in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is always invertible, for $x,y\in \mathbb{U}$, we can always find a matrix $A\in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $Ax =y$?

I feel like there should be more to it.

Comment: What is your definition of a group acting transitively?

Comment: No, it is not sufficient. The invertibility would only imply the existance of a preimage in $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer An action from $G\times S \rightarrow S$ is transitive if given $x\in S$ the $G$-orbit of $x = S$.

Comment: As a flaw in your logic, the let $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ act on the upper half plane trivially. Every element of the group is invertible. But this action is certainly not transitive. Transitivity depends on the specifics of the action, as well as on the group acting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\;z\in\Bbb C\,,\;w\in\Bbb H\;$, and write $\;w=n+im\;,\;\;n,m\in\Bbb R\;,\;m>0\;$:

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=w\iff (a-cw)z=dw-b\iff z=-\frac{dw-b}{cw-a}$$

and

$$-\frac{dw-b}{cw-a}\cdot\frac{c\overline w-a}{c\overline w-a}=-\frac{cd|w|^2-adw-bc\overline w+ab}{|cw-a|^2}=$$

$$=-\frac{ab+cd|w|^2+(ad+bc)n}{|cw-a|^2}+\frac{\overbrace{(ad-bc)}^{=1}m}{|cw-a|^2}i$$

so **also** $\;z\in\Bbb H\;$ and we're done

Comment: How does this show that there is only one orbit for the action?

Comment: @AlJebr How doesn't it?! The above shows that for **any** $\;w\in\Bbb H\;$ there exists a $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$, which *in fact* is also an element of $\;\Bbb H\;$ as shown in the second part , such that $\;z\;$ is mapped to $\;w\;$ ...

Comment: I'm just learning about transitive action. Is transitive some sort of surjective trait?

Comment: I know faithful means the actions permutation representation is injective and so does transitive mean the actions permutation representation is surjective?

Comment: I don't understand how this shows that $w \in \mathbb H$ can map to any other element in $\mathbb H$.

Comment: @AlJebr I don't think "surjective or injective" fit here. An action $\;G\times X\to X\;$ is *transitive* is for any **couple** of elements $\;x,y\in X\;$ there exists $\;g\in G\;$ s.t. $\;gx=y\;$ .

Comment: @AlJebr $\;\Bbb H\;$ maps nothing: it is $\;G:=SL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ which maps transitively $\;X:=\Bbb H\;$ into itself.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote, "I don't understand how this shows that $w \in \mathbb H$ can map to any other element in $\mathbb H$."

Comment: @AlJebr $\;z,\,w\;$ in the beginning are **any** two elements, and at the end it is shown that, in fact, $\;z\in\Bbb H\;$ as well. I honestly can't see how to simplify this any further...and perhaps "...can be mapped to..." would be clearer in english.

Comment: Why was an element from $\mathbb C$ chosen first? Why not have both $z , w \in \mathbb H$ initially?

Comment: How do you have $ad-bc=1$? Isn't this what we need to show, that there exists $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$?

Comment: @AlJebr The group $\;SL(2,\Bbb Z)\;$ is precisely the group of all integer $\;2\times2\;$ matrices with determinant $\;1\;$ ...If you don't read/learn first the basic definition of things involved here it is likely that you won't understand what's going on here.

Comment: I'm aware of the definitions. We are dealing with $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ not $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. Just because someone doesn't understand the argument does not mean they don't know the definitions. I guess you must never have any problems whatsoever following arguments ever in your life?

Comment: I would recommend you have some patience and understand not everyone gets the material so easily.

Comment: @AlJebr I've lots of patience and I told you exactly the same I'd tell to one of my students: **first**, learn and understand carefully the basic definitions, *then* you can begin to try to cope the problem: you don't know what transitive is wrt to groups actions, you don't understand why the determinant of an element in $\;SL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ equals one, you don't get why we want $\;z\in\Bbb H\;$ ...I'd say you don't know *yet* the very basic things one needs to **understand** the problem, let alone to solve it.

Comment: I know all of those definitions. I hope you know, someone can know the definitions and still have trouble solving problems. Just because you know all the definitions does not mean you are going to follow every single argument.

Comment: at the cost of being annoying: aren't you here showing that, given $a,b,c,d$ components of a matrix $A\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$, you have $A.z\in\mathbb H$ only if $z\in\mathbb H$? But to show transitivity, shouldn't you instead prove that, fixed any $z,w\in\mathbb H$, there is some $A\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$ such that $A.z=w$?

Comment: @glS  What is actually shown there is that 

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\;Az=\cfrac{az+b}{cz+d}=w\iff z=-\cfrac{dw-b}{cw-a}=\begin{pmatrix}\;\;d&-b\\-c&\;a\end{pmatrix}w=A^{-1}w\;$$

This shows the action is transitive (but still on $\;\Bbb C\times\Bbb H\;$...!),  since the rightmost part is always well defined, and what I showed in my answer is that the $\;z\;$ we get in the middle section is in fact in $\;\Bbb H\;$ and not merely in $\;\Bbb C\;$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hi, I also have the same question. If I consider the definition of transitivity as "if $X$ is non-empty and if for each pair $x, y \in X$ there exists a $g \in G$ such that $g⋅x = y.$ This is also equivalent to that $Orbit(x)=X$ for every $x \in X$." Then how to reach that step from your argument.
"

Comment: It seems that you have concluded that for any $w \in \Bbb H$ there exists $z \in \Bbb H$ s.t $A⋅z=w$ for some $A \in Sl(2, \Bbb R)$. Should I have my conclusion as transitive? How do I get it? I can also prove that it is an action and that argument is similar to your argument.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer. This answer shows that *if $Az=w$ with $z\in\Bbb C,w\in\Bbb H,A\in{\rm SL}_2\Bbb R$ then* $z\in\Bbb H$. That's not what transitivity means. Indeed, if you replace ${\rm SL}_2\Bbb R$ with $\{ I_2\}$ in that statement it would still be correct, but certainly the trivial group doesn't act transitively! What we're supposed to do is show that given any $z,w\in \Bbb H$ there exists a $A\in{\rm SL}_2\Bbb R$ such that $Az=w$.

Answer (score 27):

Let $z=x+iy$ be a given point in the upper half plane. Then the $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{y}&x/\sqrt{y} \\
0&1/\sqrt{y}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
maps $i$ to $z$. Since $z$ was arbitrary, the orbit of $i$ is the whole upper half plane. Furthermore any point $w$ can be mapped to $i$
by using the inverse of this matrix, so any $w$ can be mapped to any $z$.

Answer (score 12):

With some geometry this can be intuitively obvious, and we can say some other things.

$\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ has an Iwasawa decomposition $KAN$ where $K$ is the subgroup of rotations, $A$ is the subgroup of positive diagonal matrices, and $N$ is the subgroup of unitriangular matrices. That is, every $2\times 2$ real matrix with determinant $1$ may be uniquely expressed as

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \phantom{-}\cos\theta\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

for some angle $\theta$, scalar $\lambda>0$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $KAN$ does not refer to a direct product as groups, but it does mean $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\simeq K\times A\times N\simeq S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2$ as manifolds.

The subgroup $N$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ by translating points horizontally. The subgroup $A$ acts by homotheties (scaling every ray from the origin by a factor of $\lambda^2$). To interpret the action of $K=\mathrm{Stab}(i)$, one can interpret $\mathbb{H}$ as the upper-half plane model of the hyperbolic plane, in which case these are hyperbolic rotations around $i$.

While it is traditional to write $KAN$, to prove the decomposition more easily it is probably easier to note that $AN$ (the positive-diagonal upper triangulars) is itself a subgroup, and that $G=PQ$ is equivalent to $G=QP$ for subgroups $P,Q\le G$ (just apply inversion to all elements). This way we can prove that $AN=NA$ and then prove $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})=(NA)K$ instead.

Observe every element in $NA$ is uniquely expressible as $na$ with $n\in N$, $a\in A$. We can also see that $NA$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{H}$: given any two points $z,w\in\mathbb{H}$, we can go from $z$ to $w$ by first applying a dilation $a\in A$ so that $az$ and $w$ are at the same height (have the same imaginary part), then we apply a horizontal translation $n\in N$ so that $naz=w$. In fact, the choice of $a$ and $n$ is unique; $NA$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ regularly (i.e. $\mathbb{H}$ is a principal homogeneous space, a.k.a. a torsor). Note already proves $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively.

Finally, try the following exercise: if $H,K\le G$ are subgroups and $G$ acts on $X$ such that $H$ acts regularly and $K$ is a point-stabilizer then $G=HK$. Apply with $G=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $H=NA$ to conclude the Iwasawa decomposition.

Comment: I initially did as Stringer did, but this way is more instructive, thanks!